# Using indexes in dBase IV

Tags: sql, dbase

I have two databases which I wish to connect. Name of the first database is cenik.dbf and the name of the second database is izdaja.dbf.

cenik.dbf looks like this:

```
itemid | name

1      | some-name
2      | some-other
3      | name xy

...
```

izdaja.dbf looks like this:

```
invoice | itemid | qty

1       |1       |50
1       |2       |40
2       |1       |50    
2       |3       |40
3       |2       |10
3       |3       |40
...
```

The izdaja.dbf is a database with 25k entries and I wish to sum all the qty values for a specific itemid as fast as possible. This is the code I have so far, but it only returns the first qty at specific itemid.

```
CLEAR

SELECT 1

USE cenik

SELECT 2

USE izdaja

INDEX ON itemid TO in_izd


SELECT 1

SET RELATION TO itemid INTO izdaja

GO TOP

DO WHILE .NOT. eof()

    ?itemid    
    ??'        '    
    STORE (izdaja -> qty)  TO iz    
    ??'        '
    ??iz    
    SKIP 1
ENDDO
WAIT

CLOSE ALL

CLEAR

RETURN
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer didn't work for you, you might need to clarify more in your post.  Edit to show what you expect as output.  But I'll also offer an option.  You appear to be confused on what is going to happen in the output sample you presented.  What you have will print one record for each cenik and whatever the first qty record has in izdaja. dBASE also supports sql querying and should automatically take advantage of whatever indexes are available for the table.  If not, I would suspect it will on-the-fly create an index to help optimize for the query.

This query will get for each "Cenik" ID, the total quantity, and for grins, how many records for that ID.  Then you can scan through the output.  If you want for only a specific single ItemID, the answer provided by user304067 would be fine.

```
if used( "tmpSummary" )
   select tmpSummary
   use
endif

select;
      c.itemid,;
      c.name,;
      count(*) as TotalRecords,;
      sum(i.qty ) as TotalQty;
   from ;
      cenik c ;
         join izdaja i ;
            on c.itemid = i.itemid ;
   group by ;
      c.itemid ;
   into ;
      table tmpSummary

*/ Now, you have the data, now dump it out however you want.
select tmpSummary
do while not eof()
   ? itemid
   ?? name
   ?? TotalRecords
   ?? TotalQty
enddo

use
```

Now, if you want only a SINGLE ItemID, you could just add a SQL-Where clause before the "INTO" clause.

```
   where c.itemid = TheOneIDYouWant ;
   into table tmpSummary
```

Now, my syntax is based on years of working with Visual FoxPro (VFP) but would expect dBASE to be very close in its sql.  The only real different I can NOT confirm is its support of the "into" clause.  In VFP, you could do "into cursor Something" where it would create a MEMORY-ONLY based dbf instance of the results, so that when it is closed, so too are the temp tables used for it.  Otherwise, this sample is going into another actual TABLE that you would have to manage and delete after.

If you wanted the output in a report format, by using the SQL into a table (or Cursor), you could create a report layout and just use this result for the report without line-based ? (print) commands that as you had, are not offering any formatting or alignment.  You could also take this result and copy to an output format, such as excel via CSV and do whatever else in another tool too.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
USE izdaja
sum qty to aa(just a variable) for itemid = 1
```

The result will be the variable `aa` which will have total of `qty` for `itemid` 1